# How to read data from MySQL and show in C# label realtime when start program?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops

I read data from mysql with this code.

```
public void read_database()
{

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

    string user = "xxx";



    Console.WriteLine(user);

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySQL...");
        conn.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user = @user";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
        MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            label1.Text = rdr["number"].ToString();
        }
        rdr.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }

    conn.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
}
```

If value in table was update I want to show new value from table in realtime. So, I use while loop in Form1_Load because it will read database to show in label automatically when I start program.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    while (true)
    {
        read_database();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

    }

}
```

when I run this code it not show Form1. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is never shown because `while (true)` is an infinite loop, running on the main (UI) thread. Thus the UI thread doesn't move beyond your infinite loop. The only mechanism I'm aware of to monitor for database changes is `SqlDependency`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/detecting-changes-with-sqldependency Although I don't know if it works for MySQL.

Alternatively, you could look into using a `BackgroundWorker` to poll the database periodically. I definitely **do not** recommend polling in an infinite loop without waiting (as you tried currently, with a 3-second sleep), otherwise you'll eat up CPU and disk I/O. However, you can use a timer or similar in the `BackgroundWorker` to query on an interval. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms, you typically do this via a `Timer` component.